# A SQL Query to select two substrings from a known string

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I need a SQL query to get two charstrings from one main string, the returned values start with `T#######@@###@@####`. The main string length changes.

Example:

Main string

> @code=025121710TestPASS*68242850AD*68242382AF*1UJ97DX9AF*68248793AB*68236772AB*56054275AG*NoPN*1UW38DX9AC*NoPN*T00BE161571394 *T8LQI141529458*NoPN*NoPN*NoPN*NoPN

1st substring captured

```
T00BE161571394
```

2nd substring captured

```
T8LQI141529458
```

I've come up with this so far but to no avail:

1st substring captured

```
SELECT left(RIGHT(code, 51), 15)
```

2nd substring captured

```
SELECT left(RIGHT(code, 35), 15)
```

Can someone please help me? I am not sure how to account for the length correctly and separate the substrings in the correct order.

Comment: are you able to define a pattern describing the substrings you want to extract? Are the substrings always at the same position in the main string? Are you trying to select any row that contains those two substrings? Or extract the content of a particular pattern of substrings for all rows?

Comment: How do you define generically when the 1st substring starts & ends, as well as the 2nd? Do they always start with "T00BE" and "T8LQI", respectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this on, This will select complete list of substrings in your main string

```
declare @myString nvarchar(500)= '025121710TestPASS*68242850AD*68242382AF*1UJ97DX9AF*68248793AB*68236772AB*56054275AG*NoPN*1UW38DX9ACNoPNT00BE161571394 *T8LQI141529458*NoPNNoPNNoPN*NoPN'

;with T(ind,pos) as (
    select charindex('T', @myString), 1
    union all
    select charindex('T', substring(@myString,ind+1,len(@myString)))+ind,pos+1
    from t
    where pos > 0 and ind <> charindex('T', substring(@myString,ind+1,len(@myString)))+ind
)
select substring(@myString,ind,14) as YourString from t where substring(@myString,ind,14) NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

i guess you can use [*] to seperated. reverse string and split

```
declare @string1 nvarchar(250)
declare @string2 nvarchar(250)

declare @myString nvarchar(500)= '025121710TestPASS*68242850AD*68242382AF*1UJ97DX9AF*68248793AB*68236772AB*56054275AG*NoPN*1UW38DX9ACNoPNT00BE161571394 *T8LQI141529458*NoPNNoPNNoPN*NoPN'
set @myString = REVERSE(@myString)
DECLARE @StartPos int, @Length int

select @StartPos = CHARINDEX('*', @myString)
set @myString = SUBSTRING(@myString,(@StartPos+1),len(@myString)-@StartPos)
select @StartPos = CHARINDEX('*', @myString)
set @myString = SUBSTRING(@myString,(@StartPos+1),len(@myString)-@StartPos)


select @StartPos = CHARINDEX('*', @myString)
select @string1 = SUBSTRING(@myString,0,@StartPos)
set @myString = SUBSTRING(@myString,(@StartPos+1),len(@myString)-@StartPos)

select @StartPos = CHARINDEX('*', @myString)
select @string2 = SUBSTRING(@myString,0,16)
select REVERSE(@string1) ,REVERSE(@string2)
```