# Getting multiple varying length substrings that are separated by a specific special character from a string in SQL

Tags: sql-server, string, substring

I have a table like this:

```
Declare @TempList Table(foreignid int, petname VarChar(20), pettype VarChar(200, collarcode VarChar(20))

Insert Into @TempList Values(1000, 'Charlie', 'Dog', 'G17/G19/T22/G23')
Insert Into @TempList Values(1001, 'Tammy', 'Cat', 'P2/C233/P43')
Insert Into @TempList Values(1002, 'Oscar', 'Rat', 'B32/P414/G8221')
```

I am trying to breakout the 'collarcode' column into individual entries, so for example instead of one record of the pet 'Charlie' with a combined 'collarcode' of 'G17/G19/G22/G23', it will be multiple entries of 'Charlie' with individual 'collarcode' data.

So it will end up looking like this:

[image: desired end result]

I found this while searching [A SQL Query to select two substrings from a known string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31194612/a-sql-query-to-select-two-substrings-from-a-known-string), but while insightful, it doesn't fit what i am looking for, since it assumes the substrings are similar in length, and start with the same character.

Any help or direction would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you have SQL Server 2016, [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) is your friend (example B). If you don't have SQL Server 2016, `STRING_SPLIT` is still your friend, but a distant one that can't help you.

Comment: There are several "string split" functions here on stackoverflow... just implement one that you like best, and as a table valued function, you just cross-apply that function with your query, passing the column to be split, and it works exactly as you want.

Comment: Thanks @Jeroen Mostert and pmbAustin for recommending STRING_SPLIT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `XML` you can solve.

```
SELECT
    F1.foreignid ,
    F1.petname ,
    F1.pettype ,
    F1.collarcode ,
    O.splitdata 
FROM
(
    SELECT
        F.foreignid ,
        F.petname ,
        F.pettype ,
        F.collarcode,
        CAST('<X>'+replace(F.collarcode,'/','</X><X>')+'</X>' as XML) as xmlfilter 
    FROM @TempList F
)F1
CROSS APPLY
( 
    SELECT fdata.D.value('.','varchar(250)') AS splitdata 
    FROM f1.xmlfilter.nodes('X') as fdata(D)
) O
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much @NEER, that worked.

To anyone else, this [resource link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) helped shed more insight into the solution.